# "... conjure meaning out of the void"

Tags: sentence-meaning

What does "to conjure out of the void" mean ?

> For centuries, scientists scrutinized minute aspects of human
>   activity, but showed little interest in the time that people spent in
>   sleep. Sleep seemed inaccessible to medical probing and was perceived
>   as an unvarying period of inactivity — a subject best suited to poets
>   and dream interpreters who **could conjure meaning out of the void.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ["conjurer"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conjurer) is something akin to a wizzard or magician. He conjures things, makes things appear.

["Meaning"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meaning) is significance, the idea of something.

["The void"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Void_%28philosophy%29) is the big nothing, a completely empty space. Can be a philosophical concept, with a magician its more like "out of thin air".

If you **conjure meaning out of the void**, you make up some kind of significant something out of nothing.